# SQL Azure SaaS and licences for SSIS and SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, ssis, azure-sql-database

When subscribing to the Azure SQL SaaS. Can I get access to SSIS and SSRS?
SSIS: Does a Azure SQL subscription allow me to build SSIS package on my local computer.
SSRS: Do I need another on-premises license to run a reporting server? As I understand, there is no SaaS version for SSRS, does this mean I will have to buy a full SQL server license for reporting?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to have a VM to run SSRS which means you need IAAS. For SSIS you have Azure support using Integration runtime means you would be using SSIS Catalog in Azure SQL Database.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. To clarify, to run SSRS on the VM I'll need to purchase  a on premises SQL Server licence?  When using SSIS in an Azure context I'll have to build my SSIS packages in the cloud and cant work in a Visual Studio environment on my local computer?

Comment: When you procure a VM, you could always opt for VM with Sql Server installed else you could bring your own licensed version with you. Also there is the free Sql Server Developer edition available for solely personal usage. For SSIS, not really that you have to make the development in cloud - you would be using SSDT and then publish your packages to cloud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a `VM` to run `SSRS` which means you need `IAAS`. For `SSIS` you have `Azure` support using `Integration Runtime` means you would be using `SSIS` Catalog in `Azure SQL Database`.

When you procure a `VM`, you could always opt for `VM` with `Sql Server` installed else you could bring your own licensed version with you. Also there is the free `Sql Server Developer edition` available for solely personal usage. For `SSIS`, not really that you have to make the development in cloud - you would be using `SSDT` and then publish your packages to cloud.

Links - [deploy & run ssis package in azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/lift-shift/ssis-azure-deploy-run-monitor-tutorial?view=sql-server-2017) & [procure Integration runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-deploy-ssis-packages-azure)

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft's SaaS offering for BI and Reporting is Power BI.  Which is adding support for traditional SSRS reports, and self-service data flows. See announcement [here](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/power-bi-expands-self-service-prep-for-big-data-unifies-modern-and-enterprise-bi/).

And if for all SQL Server development, you can always use the free [SQL Server Developer Edition](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads) and [SQL Server Data Tools](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/developer-tools) on your local machine.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the SSIS component, this was very helpful! Regarding SSRS, I've had a look at the announcement and tried to closer investigate the SQL Server Reporting Technology integrated into PowerBi. Is there a more detailed explanation on what this actually means?